# How to Know which SubTask a Local Window belongs to

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to know which subtask a local window belongs to in flink streaming? I want to use the `getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask()` method in `TriggerPolicy` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way at the moment to obtain the index of the subtask on which the windowing operator with the `TriggerPolicy` is running.

However, you can work around it by putting a `map` operation in place upstream which assigns to each data element the current index of the subtask.

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<Integer, String>> ds = env.fromElements(
        new Tuple2<Integer, String>(1, "a"),
        new Tuple2<Integer, String>(2, "b"),
        new Tuple2<Integer, String>(1, "c"),
        new Tuple2<Integer, String>(2, "d"));

ds.groupBy(0)
    .map(new RichMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer,String>, Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String> map(Tuple2<Integer, String> integerStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String>(
                getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask(),
                integerStringTuple2.f0,
                integerStringTuple2.f1);
        }
    })
    .window(new TestingTriggerPolicy(), new TestingEvictionPolicy())
    .mapWindow(new WindowMapFunction<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public void mapWindow(Iterable<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String>> iterable, Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String> element : iterable) {
                builder.append(element.toString() +"; ");
            }

            collector.collect(builder.toString());
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I just know local window and it's downstream operator(for example mapWindow) are processed serially in a single thread.

Comment: @zhangshengxiong, being processed by a single or multiple threads is not a problem here. What you have to avoid is a data shuffling which will destroy the partitioning of your elements and thus the mapping of your elements to the sub task index. But as long as you use local windows, this shouldn't be a problem.